# Number repositioning

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

You are given $2^n$ numbers, in one step you move the numbers in odd positions to the beginning of the list and the numbers in even positions to the end of the list, keeping the initial order among them. Prove that after $n$ such steps, you will get the initial list.

How do I do this? Someone told me to look at positions of these numbers in binary, but I still don't understand how that helps yet...

Comment: Could looking at the position in binary help?

Comment: @WilliamElliot this is exactly what I was told.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index the $2^n$ list *positions* of elements as $\underbrace{00\ldots00}_n, \underbrace{00\ldots01}_n, \ldots,\underbrace{11\ldots10}_n, \underbrace{11\ldots11}_n$. (These are indices given to the $2^n$ positions, not to elements that may move around the list)

In each reposition / shuffle step, for the element at position $b_{n-1}b_{n-2}\ldots b_1b_0$, its destination position is at $b_0b_{n-1}\ldots b_2b_1$, i.e. a cyclic right shift of bits. This is because $b_0$ determines whether the destination is in the beginning ($0$) or ending ($1$) half, and $b_{n-1}b_{n-2}\ldots b_1$ determines the position inside that half.

After $n$ cyclic right shifts of bits, the element initially at $b_{n-1}b_{n-2}\ldots b_1b_0$ moves through positions
$$\begin{align*}
b_{n-1}b_{n-2}\ldots b_1b_0 &\mapsto b_0b_{n-1}\ldots b_2b_1\\
&\mapsto b_1b_0\ldots b_3b_2\\
&\vdots\\
&\mapsto b_{n-2}b_{n-3}\ldots b_0b_{n-1}\\
&\mapsto b_{n-1}b_{n-2}\ldots b_1b_0\\
\end{align*}$$

and goes back to its initial position.

Comment: It's more clear now, but why do you say "cyclic shift"? $00..00$ becomes $10..00$, how is that cyclic shift?

Comment: @Coder-Man $00\ldots 00$ is the first position, hence an odd position according to your question, so it should map to the first half of the list, which has a significant bit $0$.

Comment: Okay, sorry, this was confusing, because the first element is even, but it's in the odd position, so, it's like, we're now looking at positions of positions. I'll try to figure this out now and let you know if I understand it, thanks.

Comment: @Coder-Man It's confusing, so I have been avoiding considering the elements as numbers. They could be letters, apples or playing cards (riffle shuffle in reversed time). The number in the answer refers to positions, not to elements which will move around.

Comment: okay I got it, an element that's at position $i$ we put into $i/2$, which is shifting right. And elements that are in even positions we put into the second half, which starts from $2^{n-1}$, which is $10..00$, so it's like adding $1$ to the beginning.